# cisco CUCM 8.6.x configuration export

Tags: backup, cisco

We currently have a Cisco server running CUCM and cannot get access to the system due to a 'Database communication error' received when attempting a log in to CUCM homepage.

Is there any way to export configuration files from CUCM without using Bulk Administration Tool. Possibly a CLI function or a way to access config files?

Any suggestions on fixing the DB communication error too without access to the DB or CUCM GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the hostname or IP address of the Publisher prior to receiving this message? If so then you need to look at the following document:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucm/install/8_5_1/ipchange/ipchg851.html#wp42205

Thanks
Mike